# Value of scrollpx not updating on scroll in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to add an anchor tag to appear on screen after scrolling 800px. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Please have a look. The issue is the value of scrollpx is not updating on scroll.

```
<template>
 <div id="moveTop">
 <div>
  <v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex xs12 sm12 lg12>
      <b><p class="text-xs-center headings">Statement</p></b>
      </br>
      </br>
      <b><p class="text-xs-center">Statement 2</p></b>
      </br>
      <p>
        <b class="headings">Statement3</b>
      </br>
      </br>
        Statement 4
      </p>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
  <div id="scrollButton"> 
    <a class="scrollTop" href="javascript:document.getElementById('moveTop').scrollIntoView(true);" title='Click here to go to the top' v-if="scrollpx > 800"><img src="../../images/upwards.svg"></a>
  </div>    
  </div>
 </div>
</template> 

<script>

export default {    
data() {
  return {
    scrollpx: 0
  };
},
methods: {
  handleScroll() {
    this.scrollpx = window.scrollY;
  }
},
created() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
},
destroyed() {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}
}; 
</script>
```

This is the exact layout of the page. Hope I am able to provide all the necessary information.

I tried it with this simple vue file as below but it still doesn't work.

```
<template>
  <div id="moveTop">
    <div>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 sm12 lg12 >             
          <p>Statement</p>
          <p>Statement</p>
          <p>Statement</p>
          <p>Statement</p>
          <p>Statement</p>
          <p>Statement</p>
          <p>Statement</p>
          <p>Statement</p>
          <p>Statement</p>
          <p>Statement</p>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
      <div id="scrollButton"> 
        <a class="scrollTop" href="javascript:document.getElementById('moveTop').scrollIntoView(true);" title='Click here to go to the top' v-if="scrollpx > 800"><img src="../../images/upwards.svg"></a>
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Tested it here and it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-hooks-8qrwz - scroll and check the console

Comment: @T.Short Any idea what am I doing wrong on my end?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: @T.Short no errors. I checked it in the vue chrome extension. The value of scrollpx doesn't change.

Comment: @T.Short in the code you tried, put the default value of scrollpx to be 0 and the value should increase on scroll

Comment: Yes, I set it to 0 and it still works. By the way, why is the `<a>` not wrapped in `<template></template>` tags?.

Comment: @T.Short I have it inside the template tag in my actual code. I still doesn't work.

Comment: Add a `console.log` to `handleScroll`. Does it log anything when you scroll?

Comment: @T.Short it doesn't log anything on the console.

Comment: Right, so there is something wrong with the `eventlistener`. What if you change `created` to `mounted`?

Comment: Also try removing `destroyed() {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }` for now...

Comment: @T.Short I tried changing it mounted and removing destroyed() but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You may have to share the rest of your code. Or try and create a reproduceble example. Can't help much more at this point

Comment: @T.Short I have updated the question with the changes you suggested. Maybe it more clear now.

Comment: I think there may be some error in the rest of the code (you didn't post). Maybe you are scrolling in a container instead of the page?

Comment: @Chrisstar I have updated the entire layout of the page

Comment: @T.Short I have updated the entire layout of the page

Comment: @T.Short I think window.scrollY is not working. because if I console.log(window.scrollY) its value doesn't change

Comment: Do you get a value at all?

Comment: @T.Short no it just stays as 0 even on scrolling

Comment: Do you have any extra css

Comment: @T.Short I tried it with a sample file as above but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `<script>` tags around the `javascript` part:

```
<script>
export default {  
...
</script>
```

**EDIT**

Your `br` tags are wrong. `</br>` is incorrect. Change to `<br />`

Comment: I have the script tag. I just forgot to write it in the question. I have updated the question now.

Comment: Any idea about the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it working

```
<script>
  export default {    
    data() {
      return {
        scrollpx: 0
      };
    },
    methods: {
      handleScroll() {
        this.scrollpx = document.body.scrollTop;
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      document.body.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    } 
  };

</script>
```